# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, monaca

I'm making list using onsenui and react.
but I cannot call a bind from onchanged.

I couldn't figure out.... Does anyone can solve this?

this is my code.
I'd like to call handlechanged method from input item.
But then,  Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined is raised.

```js
export default class MainPage extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selectedValue: "myself",
        destinations: ["myself","somebody"],
      };
  }


  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: value});
  }

  renderRadioRow(row) {
    return (
      <ListItem key={row} tappable>
        <label className='left'>
          <Input
            inputId={`radio-${row}`}
            checked={row === this.selectedValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, row)}
            type='radio'
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={`radio-${row}`} className='center'>
          {row}
        </label>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
        <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
          test
        </p>

        <List
          dataSource={this.state.destinations}
          renderRow={this.renderRadioRow}
        />
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button that you used) are for **runnable** examples. Your example isn't runnable, so it should be in a code block (the `{}` toolbar button). But even better would be *making* it runnable, since Stack Snippets support ReactJS.

Comment: May be renderRadioRow function creates a new Context whose 'this' is used for binding  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, row)}.

Comment: Is there a canonical answer to `cannot read X of undefined`? I keep seeing these questions and in 99% of the cases the reason is readily apparent - the error message says everything needed. You are accessing X from some variable that happens to be `undefined`. Suggested course of action - find out why and either prevent it or don't access X. Match to your needs. The rest of the questions are about the same happening in a third party library. In that case, it's usually  a problem of not using it correctly. Suggested course of action - find if you've misconfigured it or are miscalling it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

No Autobinding

Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to explicitly use `.bind(this)` or arrow functions `=>:`

You can use bind() to preserve `this`

```
<div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
```

Or you can use arrow functions

```
<div onClick={() => this.tick()}>
```

We recommend that you bind your event handlers in the constructor so they are only bound once for every instance:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
```

Now you can use `this.tick` directly as it was bound once in the constructor:

It is already bound in the constructor

`<div onClick={this.tick}>`

This is better for performance of your application, especially if you implement shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow comparison in the child components.

```js
export default class MainPage extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selectedValue: "myself",
        destinations: ["myself","somebody"],
      };
      this.renderRadioRow = this.renderRadioRow.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: value});
  }

  renderRadioRow(row) {
    return (
      <ListItem key={row} tappable>
        <label className='left'>
          <Input
            inputId={`radio-${row}`}
            checked={row === this.selectedValue}
            onChange={() => {
              this.handleChange(row);
            }
            type='radio'
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={`radio-${row}`} className='center'>
          {row}
        </label>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
        <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
          test
        </p>

        <List
          dataSource={this.state.destinations}
          renderRow={this.renderRadioRow}
        />
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to call this function with row value, can I put some values to this function?

Comment: Then use the arrow function

`onChange={() => handleChange(row)}`

Comment: I tried  `() => handleChange(row)` and `() => this.handleChange(row)`. But both raised undefined handleChange error...

Comment: you need to bind `this` to renderRadioRow in order to call `this.handleChange`. I added an example

Comment: or `handleChange = (row) => {}` in your class definition. Then call it as `onChange={handleChange(row)}`

Comment: `<div onClick={() => this.tick()}>` worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what value is passed in row , but you need to pass the render context in order to call that function and bind.

```
export default class MainPage extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: "myself",
            destinations: ["myself","somebody"],
        };
    }


    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({selectedValue: value});
    }

    renderRadioRow(row,renderContext) {
        return (
            <ListItem key={row} tappable>
                <label className='left'>
                    <Input
                        inputId={`radio-${row}`}
                        checked={row === this.selectedValue}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(renderContext, row)}
                        type='radio'
                    />
                </label>
                <label htmlFor={`radio-${row}`} className='center'>
                    {row}
                </label>
            </ListItem>
        )
    }

    render() {
        var renderContext=this;
        return (
            <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
                <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    test
                </p>

                <List
                    dataSource={this.state.destinations}
                    renderRow={() => this.renderRadioRow(row,renderContext)}
                />
            </Page>
        );
    }
}
```