# React： Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I face a question as flow：

```
class App extends React.Component {

  testop(){
    alert("test");
  }

  showAlert() {
    // alert("Im an alert");
    this.testop();
  }
  

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.showAlert}>show alert</button>;
  }
}
```

when I run the code, the error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testop')". why cannot read testop function？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined. React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632811/cannot-read-property-bind-of-undefined-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `this` you are referring to inside `showAlert` is not referring to component's `this` instead it is referring to the internal methods `this`.

There are two solutions for this problem.

Either bind the function with component's this inside the component's constructor:

```
constructor (){
  this.showAlert = this.showAlert.bind(this);
}
```

Or use ES6's arrow function which provides lexical scoping

Answer (score 0):

or try to use arrow function instead of binding

```
showAlert = () => {
  this.testop();
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-ully-1ynyqm?file=/src/App.js